# Is there any similarity in cooking items by Vallav (Bheema) and Bahuka (Nala) in Mahabharatha during their tough times?

Tags: mahabharata, food, bhima, nala

Mahabharata has Nalopakyana Parva, which explains the life of Nala in some chapters.

Nala appoints as rider and chef in the court of Rithuparna. Bheema was appointed as entertainer and chef in the court of Virata.

There are several similarities between the story of Nala and the story of Pandavas in multiple aspects.

I want to know whether there is any similarity in the items of cooking by Nala and Bheema.

A passage says that Nala cooked meat of various animals during the visit to Vidarbha.

> "Vrihadaswa said, 'Hearing everything, Damayanti became oppressed with
> grief, and suspecting the person to be Nala, said unto Kesini, 'O
> Kesini, go thou again, and examine Vahuka, and staying in silence at
> his side mark thou his conduct. And, O beauteous one, whenever he
> happens to do anything skilful, do thou observe well his act while
> accomplishing it. And, O Kesini, whenever he may ask water or fire,
> with the view of offering him obstruction, thou shalt be in no hurry
> to give it. And marking everything about his behaviour, come thou and
> tell me. And whatever human or super-human thou seest in Vahuka,
> together with anything else, should all be reported unto me.' And thus
> addressed by Damayanti, Kesini went away, and having marked the
> conduct of that person versed in horse-lore, she came back. And she
> related unto Damayanti all that had happened, indeed, everything of
> human and superhuman that she had witnessed in Vahuka. And Kesini
> said, 'O Damayanti, a person of such control over the elements I have
> never before seen or heard of. Whenever he cometh to low passage, he
> never stoopeth down, but seeing him, the passage itself groweth in
> height so that he may pass through it easily. And at his approach,
> impassable narrow holes open wide. **King Bhima had sent various kinds
> of meat--of diverse animals, for Rituparna's food. And many vessels
> had been placed there for washing the meat. And as he looked upon
> them, those vessels became filled (with water). And having washed the
> meat, as he set himself to cook**, he took up a handful of grass and
> held it in the sun, when fire blazed up all on a sudden. Beholding
> this marvel, I have come hither amazed. Further, I have witnessed in
> him another great wonder. O beauteous one, he touched fire and was not
> burnt. And at his will, water falling floweth in a stream. And, I have
> witnessed another greater wonder still. He took up some flowers, began
> to press them slowly with his hands. And pressed by his hand, the
> flowers did not lose their original forms, but, on the contrary,
> became gayer and more odorous than before. Having beheld wonderful
> things I have come hither with speed.'"
>
> [[Section 75, Nalopakhyana Parva, Vana Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03075.htm)

In this context, I want to know whether there is any mention of food items Bheema used to cook during his time in the Virata kingdom.